# Excel if value appears in any column, average the reference column

Tags: excel, vba

I need to find the average of a number found in column F if a particular value is found in any of the other columns in the sheet.

For instance: I have the following in a range...

```
     A        B         C         D         E        F
```

1. Red     Bill      Jack    Ruby     Bill     250
2. Blue       Ruby   Ivan    Raul      Ted    350
3. Green    Ted     James      Rick       Ted   125
4. Red     Ted     Phil     Ruby      Bill    300

And in this worksheet, I want to find any instance of the name Bill and get the average of the number found in column F. In this case, the answer of 275 because Bill's name shows up in two rows. In the same respect, If I choose to look at Ted's numbers, the answer should be 258 because Ted's name shows up in three rows.

I would also appreciate if the formula would ignore any blank cells in the process of calculating the answer.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the function below, assuming that the data is placed in `Sheet1`.

```
Function my_average(strName As String) As Variant
 Dim varArrayNames As Variant
 Dim varValues As Variant
 Dim dblInSum(1 To 4) As Double '~~> change to "1 To 40"
 Dim lngCnt As Long
 Dim strRow As String
 Dim dblSum As Double

 varArrayNames = Sheet1.Range("B1:E4").Value '~~> change to "B1:G40"
 varValues = Sheet1.Range("F1:F4").Value    '~~> change to "H1:H40"

 For lngCnt = LBound(varArrayNames, 1) To UBound(varArrayNames, 1)
     strRow = Join(WorksheetFunction.Index(varArrayNames, lngCnt, 0))
     If InStr(strRow, strName) > 0 Then
       dblInSum(lngCnt) = 1
     End If
 Next lngCnt

 dblSum = WorksheetFunction.Sum(dblInSum)

 If dblSum > 0 Then
   my_average = WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(dblInSum, Application.Transpose(varValues)) / dblSum
 Else
  my_average = 0
End If

End Function
```

Testing:

Place `=my_average("Bill")` in any workbook (or a cell reference instead of "Bill").

Formulas:
[image]

Results:

[image]

Comment: This works great as long as the array is 4 lines long. My array always has 6 columns and the value is in a 7th column. However, my array can range from 8 to 36 rows every month. Is there a way to use this with variable sizes of arrays?

Comment: I have updated the answer so that it solves the generic version too. Three parts need to be edited, as shown in the in-line comments. Storing the data in VBA arrays makes the calculations pretty fast, even for tens of hundreds times more data, so I would just fix the rows to 40 (or even more), as suggested in the comments.

Comment: That did the trick, and it worked perfectly! Is there any chance this sort of answer would work to answer this problem as well? [Counts the number of times a value appears in a group of columns but counts only one instance per row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43374008/excel-counts-the-number-of-times-a-value-appears-in-a-group-of-columns-but-count?rq=1)

Comment: Yes, that is easy: just remove the last `If` block altogether and put `my_average=dlbSum` instead. Probably a better name for the function would be a good idea too.

Comment: That too worked amazingly well! Thanks again for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the lookup value (Bill etc) is in cell C7, add the following formula in G1 then copy down for other rows.

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH($C$7,A1:E1,0)),"",F1)
```

Then do

```
=AVERAGE(G1:G4)
```

Answer (score -1):

So if Bill is in any col a-e that number is taking into the ave...  If so depending on your data size why not do this simply...:

```
Sub simplesearch()
    cnt = 0
    tot = 0
    srchval = InputBox("What are we looking for?")
    lr = Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To lr
        For j = 1 To 5
            If Cells(i, j).Value = srchval Then
                tot = tot + Cells(i, 6).Value
                cnt = cnt + 1
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    If Not (cnt = 0) Then
        MsgBox (tot / cnt)
    Else
        MsgBox ("0")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Jon! This works well but I would need it to automatically calculate these numbers from another sheet based on the name of each person in the sheet so they can see their average. Is there a way to get the macro to automatically calculate each name's average and place it into a cell onto the next sheet?

Comment: I would change it to a function then instead of msg box output it... then take your cols and combine them into 1 and then do a unique on it.

Comment: This shows 266.667 instead of 275 for Bill because it double counts the first row. To avoid this, it needs an `Exit For` statement under the `If` clause. Also, if there are any blanks within Bill's cell it will return 0.